# First and Last day of Week + Month in Twig

Tags: templating, datetime

If i provide the week#, how might i go about getting the first day (and month) and the last day (and month) of that particular week?

This week for instance would be April 26 and May 2

I know in PHP i can do the first and last day of the week like so:

```
$day = date('w');
$week_start = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-'.$day.' days'));
$week_end = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+'.(6-$day).' days'));
```

But i'm not sure how to translate that to twig and of course also include the month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That code in Twig would be:

```
{% set day = now|date('w') %}
{% set weekStart = now|date_modify("-#{day} days")|date('m-d-Y') %}
{% set weekEnd = now|date_modify("+#{6-day} days")|date('m-d-Y') %}
```

Comment: I noticed that there's a difference between `now` and `'now'`, Brandon. `now` not returning the date calculated to be in the right timezone?

Comment: @carlcs We fixed that in [Craft 2.4.2670](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2670) :)

Answer (score 5):

The version below could be more understandable in some cases.

First day of week *(assuming Monday is the first day)*:

```
{{ now | date_modify('monday this week') | date('m-d-Y') }}
```

or alternatively:

```
{{ now | date_modify('this week') | date('m-d-Y') }}
```

Last day of week *(assuming Sunday is the last day)*:

```
{{ now | date_modify('sunday this week') | date('m-d-Y') }}
```

First day of month:

```
{{ now | date_modify('first day of this month') | date('m-d-Y') }}
```

Last day of month:

```
{{ now | date_modify('last day of this month') | date('m-d-Y') }}
```